# How to train multiple matrix with binary arrays

Tags: python, arrays, machine-learning, matrix

I have seven matrix with several arrays. Each array has binary elements, and each matrix is a class of an signal from electrocardiograms.
For training i have 7 matrix, each matrix has 110 arrays with a lot of binary elements( just 0 and 1, where 1 is the white space and 0 is the black part witch represents the signal) that represent the ecg signal.
For test i have 7 matrix the same, with 30 arrays.

How it is supposed to make a model to train these matrics and how should i do to do this machine learning algorithm? 
This is how a matrix for train looks like

```
[[1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.] ->this is array 1
 [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.] ->this is array 2
 [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
 ...//here are a lot of numbers, including 0
 [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]] -> this is array 110
```

And this is how matrix of test looks like:

````
[[1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.] ->this is array 1
 [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.] ->this is array 2
 [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
 ... //here are a lot of numbers, including 0
 [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]] -> this is array 30```
````

Comment: if you transform it into a numpy array every machine learning algorithm can handle it since they're all categorical features. There's a lot of examples here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/

Answer (score 0):

Transform it into a numpy array and train it using a machine learning model. Here's a sample

```
import numpy as np 
features=np.random.choice([0,1], (110,6), p=[0.5, 0.5]) # Generating random numpy array with values 0&1 for training
targets = np.random.choice([0,1], (110,), p=[0.5, 0.5])
test_features = np.random.choice([0,1], (50,6), p=[0.5, 0.5]) # Test set
test_targets = np.random.choice([0,1], (50,), p=[0.6, 0.4])

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier # Training algo of your choice
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score 
model = DecisionTreeClassifier() 
model.fit(features,targets)
pred = model.predict(test_features) # Inference of test set
accuracy_score(test_targets,pred) # Evaluation
```